# AngularJS, NodeJS: save data to a Json file or a database

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, angularjs, post

I am new to AngularJS and nodeJS And I can't seem to find the information I need, I am hoping someone here can help.
I am creating this small app as a training, it's basically a personal lexicon: the user (for now, just me) can enter all the info they want to keep on hand, and refer to when needed.

My issue is the storage part, the database.
I went for a simple json file, which I can read through my AngularJS app quite easily. But trouble comes when I need to store a new entry.
After some reading I realised that a POST request was not going to work, as javascript, or angularjs, or nodejs, do not permit writing in local files (or in general) and that I needed to go through another service that would make that possible. Is that correct?

I better share my different files:

1/ My index.html calling the form directive:

```
    <div class="container" ng-controller="EntryController as ctrl">
        <entry-form data="ctrl.entry" submit="ctrl.submitEntry();"></entry-form>
    </div>
```

2/ My form Directive:

```
function entryForm () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        bindToController: {
            data: '=',
            submit: '&',
        },
        controller: 'FormController as form',
        templateUrl: 'templates/entry-form.html'
    };
};


angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('entryForm', entryForm);
```

3/ My form template:

```
<form name="orderForm" ng-submit="form.onSubmit()">
    <input required="" ng-minlength=2 ng-maxlength=15 name="title" type="text" ng-model="form.data.title" placeholder="Title">
    <input required="" name="topic" type="text" ng-model="form.data.topics" placeholder="Topic1">
    <input name="topic" type="text" ng-model="form.data.topics" placeholder="Topic2">
    <input name="topic" type="text" ng-model="form.data.topics" placeholder="Topic3">
    <textarea required="" name="text" ng-model="form.data.content" placeholder="Content" name="" id="" cols=42 rows="5"></textarea>
    <input name="link" type="text" ng-model="form.data.link" placeholder="Link">
    <input required="" name="category" type="text" ng-model="form.data.mainCategory" placeholder="Main category">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

4/ My form controller:

```
function FormController () {
    this.onSubmit = function () {
        console.log('submitting at formController level')
        this.submit();
    };
};

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('FormController', FormController);
```

5/ My model controller:

```
function EntryController ($http) {
    const ctrl = this;
    const API = '../database/lexicon.json';

    this.entry = {
    title: "",
    topics: [],
    content: "",
    link: "",
    mainCategory: ""
    };
    this.submitEntry = function () {
        // communicate with the API
        console.log("testing");
        console.log(this.entry);
        $http
        .post(API, "hello my friend")
        .then(function() {
            console.log("successful");
        });
    };
};


angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('EntryController', EntryController);
```

6/ my lexicon controller:

```
function LexiconController ($http) {
    const ctrl = this;
    const API = '../database/lexicon.json';
    this.lexicon = [];
    $http
        .get(API)
        .then(function (response) {
            ctrl.lexicon = response.data.entries;
        });
};

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('LexiconController', LexiconController)
```

I hope that I didn't miss anything, otherwise let me know.
Of course, my POST method doesn't work and returns a `405 (Method Not Allowed)`

How would you suggest I go about it so that the user can do all the necessary CRUD actions on that json file? (here it is by the way, with data that I have inputed manually)

```
{
    "entries": [{
        "title": "testing",
        "topics": [],
        "content": "",
        "link": "",
        "mainCategory": "Rails"
        },{
        "title": "Trying again",
        "topics": [],
        "content": "",
        "link": "",
        "mainCategory": "AngularJS"
    }]
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have a look at [lowdb](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb), this is exactly what it is designed for.

For example, assuming a file "entries.json":

**entries.json**

```
{
    "entries": [{
        "title": "testing",
        "topics": [],
        "content": "",
        "link": "",
        "mainCategory": "Rails"
        },{
        "title": "Trying again",
        "topics": [],
        "content": "",
        "link": "",
        "mainCategory": "AngularJS"
    }]
}
```

**test.js**

```
const low = require('lowdb')
const FileSync = require('lowdb/adapters/FileSync')

const dbFileName = "entries.json";
const adapter = new FileSync(dbFileName)
const db = low(adapter)

// Add another entry
db.get('entries')
.push({
    "title": "Here's a new entry",
    "topics": [],
    "content": "",
    "link": "",
    "mainCategory": "Node.js"
    })
.write();
```

This would end up looking like so:

```
{
"entries": [
    {
      "title": "testing",
      "topics": [],
      "content": "",
      "link": "",
      "mainCategory": "Rails"
    },
    {
      "title": "Trying again",
      "topics": [],
      "content": "",
      "link": "",
      "mainCategory": "AngularJS"
    },
    {
      "title": "Here's a new entry",
      "topics": [],
      "content": "",
      "link": "",
      "mainCategory": "Node.js"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Great, it's a very useful library :-)

Comment: Yes it looks like it. But I have encountered another problem. When I use your exemple and launch the test.js in the terminal everything works perfectly. But when I integrate the same process to my controller, and launch the app using ``` npx http-server -o ```
I get an error message: ```require is not defined ```
Maybe I should open a new topic for that.

Comment: Ah, yes, you might need to use an import statement rather than a require statement, the example I posted was using Node.js which uses CommonJS modules rather than ES6 modules. For example using import low from 'lowdb' instead of low = require("lowdb");

Comment: Thanks! I tried it the way you wrote it and like this. ```import { low } from 'lowdb';
import { FileSync } from 'lowdb/adapters/FileSync';```
And it's not working. I get this error: ```Cannot use import statement outside a module```
No worries I'll look it up, you've helped a lot already!